# Can we have approval history in the approval page in lightning

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

In Classic,when we click on approve/reject link the page which opens will be having approval history,but in lightning the approval history is not visible.Is there any way we can make approval history available in lightning also..

Below are the screenshot in classic and lightning.

Classic

[image]

Ligtning

[image]

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible as of now. Unless you create your own custom UI when you allow user to approve/reject as well as show previous history as well.

You can vote this idea: [Show Approval History on Approval in Lightning](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000TqpkQAC)

You can get the custom UI Idea from here: [Replica Of Approval Process History Using Apex And Visualforce Page](http://www.ajay-gupta.com/2015/12/09/replica-of-approval-process-history-using-apex-and-visualforce-page/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Tushar.....If we make our own custom UI...Can i add approval history in that page which can be seen in lightning?

Comment: @user46777 yes with custom UI thats possible. But I don't think you can add that page in standard approval page.

Comment: Then you mean to say this is not possible using Custom UI also as we can't add it to the standard approval page.... can we have custom approval page instead? I am new to approval concept so want to know...it will be of great help..

Comment: @user46777 Yes you need a custom approval page.

Comment: Thank you tushar :-).Can you please share the link if you know... if someone has already tried this method for reference?

Comment: @user46777 answer updated with link.

Comment: Thanks a lot tushar...one last question that i have is "approval page" which we get when we click on approve/reject link is standard and it is read only.... We can add some fields to it by going to that approval process....If i have custom page for that how i will link that page with the approval process...?

Comment: @user46777 its better if you post a separate question for this. You can get better answer. Also you can close this question.

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce has made approval history related list available in LEX now. Just make sure that you've added it on layout and after that you can place it anywhere on lightning record page with help of standard component "Related List-Single"

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have created a custom component using a Visualforce and an Extension Controler, you can see the code here: https://gist.github.com/emoran/04696b57600e0f892ffa714c88b80a54

and the final result is like this, Hope it helps.

[image]