# Assigning the Custom approval Page

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I have a requirement where in approval page,the approval history should be displayed. 
[Approval History in lightning](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215080/can-we-have-approval-history-in-the-approval-page-in-lightning/215082?noredirect=1#comment325463_215082),so for this i have got the answer in the above link. As we can't add the custom vf page in the standard approval page.So i wanted to know where i can add the custom vf page.So that whenever i click on the approve/reject link the custom vf page opens up.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.ajay-gupta.com/2015/12/09/replica-of-approval-process-history-using-apex-and-visualforce-page/ check this

Comment: Hi Prabhat,The link has the code to develop custom page...But i want to know how i can assign the custom page developed to the Approval layout.